# Best way to re-start HDD spin-down countdown on external enclosure

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd

I have an external HDD enclosure (RaidSonic Icy Box) and drives (HGST NAS) tends to spin-down after 5 minutes of no activity, but I need 'em to stay alive until I shut it down manually.

It's normally connected via USB3.0, so `hdparm` doesn't do anything. I tried also via eSATA, but `hdparm` is not working as well (tried couple different settings) and drives spins-up immediately after going to spin-down, so it's even worse...

I think that this 5-minute timer is related to enclosure itself, not OS.

I wrote I simple workaround script that performs an operation on a file to reset countdown:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /media/my/drive/.alive
while (true); do
    truncate -s 0 dummy
    sleep 270 # 4:30
done
```

(`dir` or `ls` does not reset the countown, seems like those are reading from cache)

I don't mind running another terminal, that's even better, I can shut it down whenever I want and drives will then spin-down.
However I would like to know if there's a better way ? Something that does not write anything on a drive (like modifying file), but just sending simple "keep-alive" signal ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it will work for you but you can try opening terminal and typing

```
gsku gnome-disks &
```

or I guess if you don't have gksu you can type

```
sudo gnome-disks &
```

Then select the external drive and click the icon in the right top that looks like three vertical lines and choose `Drive Settings` You can set the standby timeouts there ... again not sure if this will work for your situation but its worth a try :D It may have the same issue because of it being an external HD though  so not sure it will work but I can't test  it myself because I don't have the availability of an external HD

if you don't have gnome-disks installed you can install it by using

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

Comment: It's not available via USB so I tried with eSATA. Changed timeout to "Never" and APM level to "128" and unfortunately it did not help :( This countdown must be an enclosure feature and I think the only way is to send some command to the drive to reset the timer.

Comment: yeah it may be built into the firmware of the enclosure ... You can probably pick up a cheap hd enclosure on newegg or amazon .. basically its just a hard drive in there so changing the enclosure isn't a real big deal ... maybe another one would not have this built in timer .. if you can find one cheap enough its worth a try .. if it doesn't work you can just grab yourself another hd and have 2 externals :D lol

Comment: I need good/expensive enclosure with RAID-1 :)

Comment: oh yeah ... i can understand that .. ok guess that's not a cheap "testing" option then ... well hopefully that other guys answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

The problem with hdparm appears to most likely be your implementation of hdparm as hdparm does normally control external drives connected via USB.

It is however, quite common for hdparm to ignore spindown settings. Miany times, is rnecessary to find which setting  is honored or accepted by your hardware.

An apm setting of 255 is supposed to disable spindown altogether, however, many systems require you use 254 instead.

If this still does not work, please post your hdparm configuration and any related error

Comment: With USB `-B 255 -S 0` and `-B 254 -S 0` did not help and with eSATA I already tried those yesterday. This timer must be controled by enclosure, not OS. I need a simplest-possible command to re-start the timer.